# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty (\frac{ln(1+x^2)}{(x+a)^2})$

Tags: calculus

I thought about using majorant criterion since $(x+a)^2\gt x^2$ for positive $a$ but that didn't lead anywhere.

For negative $a$ function is discontinuous at $x=-a$ so

$\int_0^{-a} (\frac{ln(1+x^2)}{(x+a)^2})$ $+$ $\int_{-a}^\infty (\frac{ln(1+x^2)}{(x+a)^2})$

I thought about using limit criterion on the second one since integrad is positive but that also didn't work out .

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for $a \leq 0$:

From continuity, you can show that for some real $b$ and some real $C > 0$, $a < x < b \implies \ln (1+x^2) > C$.

Hint for $a > 0$:

For any real $n>0$, there is a real $a>0$ so that $x > a \implies \ln x < x^n$. Here I'd take $n = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Could you elaborate a bit more?